# Pattern matching operator broken for ValueTuple?

Tags: c#, .net-6.0

Using `.NET 6` and `C# 10`. Consider this simple type-check:

```cs
(object, bool) untyped = new("", false);

if (untyped is (string, bool) typed)
{
    Console.WriteLine(typed.GetType());
}
```

And the output:

> System.ValueTuple`2[**System.Object**,System.Boolean]

So I managed to have the cookie and eat it at the same time. Apparently, the `typed` variable is of type `(string, bool)` *and* `(object, bool)`.

I'm trying to wrap my head around this. It's tempting to state that the *"compiler is broken"* but maybe I've misunderstood some `C#` fundamentals.

### Update

[Example code on SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgNAJiDUAfAAgJgIwFgBQyDMABGgQMIEDeOB1RhyALAQLIAUAlBVTdywPYBGAKwCmAY2BQC/XrwgcArgDtgATwAOwmAQC8BFgCJ9kgGYBDCAGdhbANzcCAegcEAyqYC2wggEkAMgEIuez0BEXFJaVkFZXVNVB0CRWEAdwMjAjNLazsnVw8vP0DsYOog+zBjPSVVDS0wCz1kdAAGCJk5AhrNNjLuSmKS7iaAThYumAA6AHFhYAAVWPZbXpoAXzL17FWgA==).

The `IL` speaks for itself.

### Question

Please explain the ambiguity of this type-check! Is the pattern matching operator broken?

Comment: `Untyped` is actually a `(string, bool)` but because `string` is an `object`, it can be assigned to an `(object, bool)` variable.

Comment: @JayBuckman You're right that a `(string, bool)` can be converted to an `(object, bool)`, but that's not what's happening here. It would be what happened if OP typed `(object, bool) untyped = ("", false)` (well, except the compiler optimized it), but they used `new("", false)"`. That `new` is target-typed to `(object, bool)`, so it really does compile to `new ValueTuple<object, bool>("", false)`. [See here](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0ATEBqAPgAQCYBGAWACgKAKCYAKxjABc0ACYCCAGwEpWBXAHZMAngAcYGVgF5WgmAHdWVAEQq2AMwCGXAM4weAbiA==)

Comment: And even if OP had used `("", false)`, the compiler handles the conversion to `(object, bool)` by literally tearing the tuple apart then putting it back together. There would be no trace of the original `(string, bool)`, so this wouldn't explain the problem. [See here](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0ATEBqAPgNwEMoACAFwEYSBeEgCgCIG0SAzQgGwGcYBKAbgCwAKDoRgAKxhgyLYBAgde5AEw1yFIcJFA===)

Comment: Not sure what you're discussing. `(", false)` and `new(", false)` are equivalent. You can use whichever syntax you want on line 1 as long as the variable type is indeed `(object, bool)`.

Comment: @l33t It's because Jay claimed that `untyped` is actually a `(string, bool)`, which is incorrect. The variable is of type `(object, bool)`. The stuff about assigning between `(string, bool)` and `(object, bool)` is correct but doesn't apply here. `("", false)` and `new("", false)` are subtly different, as the former constructs a `(string, bool)` and the latter constructs an `(object, bool)`, but the distinction is not relevant to your question.

Comment: Actually, the compiler will **not** construct a `(string, bool)` on line 1, as demonstrated in the linked SharpLab sample.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I said. It will optimize the `(object, bool) untyped = ("", false)` case, so you won't see the difference unless you introduce an intermediate: [see here](https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgbghgTgAgB4ILwIBQCIsBoEBmMANgM4CmAlANwCwAUBgPYBGAVuQMYAu+LTTYpQQBPNMmpA==)

Comment: I stand corrected.  And now I'm confused and curious...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* that's happening is that the logic is the same as:

```
if (c is (string, bool) d)
{
    // 'd' is a instance of 'C', not a tuple
}

public class C
{
    public void Deconstruct(out object o, out bool b) => (o, b) = ("", false);
}
```

[SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LgTgrgdgNAJiA1AHwG4EMwAIDGWC8WUApgO5YDCAFAJQDcAsAFACWAZllXiwM6cACARgAMMLACMA9pIA2NLHBrMA3syzqszAL7Nm/AMxZ+AJkoq1Gg0YAsWACLEckqD2CQcwKpIjAsk8QBWjr6SYt6+UrIS8vgAfJyh0QScAEQpYmzoMjzE9NpAA==).

Which is probably more useful as e.g.:

```
if (c.D is (string, bool) and { Length: >0 } d)
{
    // 'd' is an instance of 'D'
}

public class C
{
    public D D { get; set; } = new();
}

public class D
{
    public int Length { get; set; }
    public void Deconstruct(out object o, out bool b) => (o, b) = ("", false);
}
```

[SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LgTgrgdgNAJiA1AHwG4EMwAIDGWC8WUApgO5YDCAFAJQDcAsAFACWAZllTgHQAiWLAM6cAAgEYADDCwAjAPZyANjSzoocLAG8sAGWJQA5sAAWILAD4JWAL5Y4NZpuZYXWAPRusAcjheBwtQEoQWA1HGIsOQ4vXi9ma2ZmEQBmLBEAJkpHZ1cUrH5+bQNiYDosQRKy20ISUlpGJgSmJNSM/OymVzTUlihgXX0jYy0sYtLyypsclzyRABZ84hw5YOBIHGAqOQh+uRkAKyXd6W3++SVZFXxzTjlpGSvOACIn6TZ0RQr6eKA==).

That is, the `is (...)` pattern is a [positional pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/patterns#positional-pattern) and not a [type pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/patterns#declaration-and-type-patterns). In a positional pattern, we're deconstructing the object and applying patterns to each of its parts, but the designation `d` applies to the object we're applying the positional pattern to, and not to a tuple constructed of its parts.

I agree this is highly confusing when we're just matching against a tuple as in your question. It does make a bit more sense in my second example above however, where `c.D` might be a complex expression and we want the ability to bind it to a variable while also applying patterns to it.

The actual [spec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/patterns#positional-pattern) doesn't seem to cover this case: it doesn't specify what type `simple_designation` is or what it's bound to.

Comment: So if you type `if (someObj is int i)` you are actually using a slightly **different** `C#` feature? In that case, there would be no deconstruction and the type of `i` would indeed be `System.Int32`. Now that's just crazy.

Comment: Yes - that's a type pattern, not a positional pattern

Comment: So the type pattern and positional pattern have pretty much the same syntax? I still don't understand why you can declare **a variable** after the `(x, y)` pattern. Makes no sense...

Comment: It seems that in patterns, `(...)` can't be used to construct a tuple, as that syntax is reserved for positional patterns (and therefore deconstruction). You'll need to use `ValueTuple<...>` instead

Comment: Do you think this is a compiler bug or a design decision?

Comment: It looks like a design decision to me -- everything's working as written in the specification